# Add & remove JTextField at runtime in Java(Swings) program

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt

how to add and remove components(JButons , JTextField  etc) at runtime in a Swing program (Java ) , without using NetBeans ? which Layout should I use ?
I want the user to enter Username & Password and , when he clicks on Submit button , the new screen with new components(JButtons , JTextField etc) should appear , I am unable to achieve the transition at runtime.

Comment: I've run into this problem before and all the answers so far seem good to me; I've used them all in different scenarios.

Comment: Given that he specifically is creating a username/password panel, I would not choose any of the solutions that involve reusing this same panel for other purposes.  It's just bad design practice.  I could think of other situations where a panel could be reused, but not this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use two different panels to achieve this result.  It's not a good idea to use the same panel and remove all of the first components and add all of the second ones.

Make a LoginPanel class which lays out the username and password fields, labels, and submit button.  Then, when the submit button is pressed, after the login is authenticated, hide the login panel and display a new panel with the layout you want for the next screen.

This sort of approach makes it much easier to maintain the two panels, and clearly separates their layouts and functionality from each other.

You can center this new frame over the existing panel using this code:

```
public static void centerFrameOverComponent(JFrame frame, JComponent component) {
    Window parent = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(component);

    Rectangle frameRect = frame.getBounds();
    Rectangle parentRect = parent.getBounds();

    int x = (int) (parentRect.getCenterX() - frameRect.getWidth() / 2);
    int y = (int) (parentRect.getCenterY() - frameRect.getHeight() / 2);

    frame.setLocation(x, y);
}
```

Comment: After login , if I set the visibility of one JFrame false , and then set the visibility of another JFrame true, then the new JFrame is not aligned where the last frame was on the screen(given that the user changed previous JFrame's alignment by dragging the window .Can you give me a solution to this ? Should I make JPanel inside JFrame instead ?

Comment: You can use two panels in the same frame and swap them out, or you can open a new frame and center it with some additional code:

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to use [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). Your login button handler would check the credentials and use [`show()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#show%28java.awt.Container,%20java.lang.String%29) to reveal the second pane.

Addendum: For security, consider using [`JPasswordField`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html) for the password; for convenience, consdier [`setLocationRelativeTo()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo%28java.awt.Component%29) for positioning the frame.

Comment: I think that show() is deprecated, setVisible(true) should be used instead

Comment: @Phobia: `CardLayout#show()` is _not_ deprecated. Perhaps you're thinking of `Window#show()`: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html

Comment: setLocationRelativeTO(null) is great api to centre align the frame , thanks trashgod .

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to call `setVisible(false)` on the specific component when you wish to hide it.

In cases where I have wanted to add/remove an entire sub panel, I have used the following:

```
panel.remove(subPanel);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

You want to call the last two methods whenever you add/remove components.

Answer (score 2):

you could create a new class for exsample MyFrame thath extends JFrame, that rapresetns your new windows, in the constructor of that class you have to add at the contentpanel your all contolr....

in this way you can add a jbutton to your JFrame.

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame{

    private JButton jb= new JButton("hello");

    public MyFrame(){
        setSize(new Dimension(300,180));  //set the MyFrame size
        getContentPane().add(jb);  //add your Component at ContentPane
    }

}
```

after the login you could show your new frame in this way:

```
new MyFrame().setVisible(true);
```

Comment: if I set the visibility of one JFrame false , and then set the visibility of another JFrame (after login) , then the new JFrame is not aligned where the last frame was on the screen(given that the user changed previous JFrame's alignment by dragging the window .Can you give me a solution to this ?